# When will flux be negative? Line integrals and vector fields

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If the circulation is negative and flux is clearly not zero then will the flux also be negative?

If a curve C and its vector field are going in opposite directions (meaning C is going clockwise and the vector field is going counterclockwise), then circulation will be negative. If the vector field is pointing outwards from the curve meaning it is leaving the curve then will the flux remain positive?

[image]

Comment: Added a picture in order to get a better idea of what I might be asking. To the people who downvoted, just try and ask for further clarification instead of downvoting for no reason.

Comment: The line integral in the picture is negative. The flux of that VF *out* of the region enclosed by that curve is positive.

Comment: My professor has stated that the flux is negative using this picture. I can't seem to understand how they might have reached this conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Take the unit circle oriented counterclockwise. The radial vector field $\vec F = \vec x$ clearly has positive flux and zero circulation. Now perturb it very slightly and you can make the circulation negative (rotate the vectors $\epsilon$ clockwise). So the answer to your question is no.

Comment: My professor has stated that the flux is negative using this picture. I can't seem to understand how they might have reached this conclusion. I can see how the direction of the curve is clockwise hence that helps with circulation, but I am unsure about the flux.

Comment: Your question referred only to the diagram? That was far from clear. Your professor is correct. Because the circle is oriented clockwise, the normal vector points inward. The diagram makes it clear that the projection of the vector field on the *inward* normal is a negative multiple of the normal.

Comment: So clockwise or counterclockwise is the determination for whether the flux will be negative or positive? In other words, a clockwise curve will have normal vectors point inward and the opposite for counterclockwise?

Comment: Yes, the normal and the tangent to the curve (in that order) always forms a right-handed system.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you.